# ModalPopupExtender OnShow event?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Using the asp.net AjaxControlToolkit ModalPopupExtender is there a way listen to an event when the TargetControlID is clicked and the Modal becomes visible?

something like an OnShow or an OnClose method which can be run on the server

Thanks

Comment: maybe i should just start using jquery thickbox http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to move to the Thickbox thanks to help from [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/masterdetail_with_the_gridview_1.html) post.